# Rails Custom Renderer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, renderer

I've been trying to create a custom renderer based on [this Yehuda Katz's blog post](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/render-options-in-rails-3/).

It works if I call `render :my_custom_renderer => "index"`, but it doesn't work with default `respond_with` or `format.my_custom_renderer`

I created a simple example, .

From a blank app, add the following lines:

In config/mime_types.rb:

```
Mime::Type.register_alias 'text/html', :my_custom_renderer
```

In config/my_custom_renderer.rb:

```
require "action_controller/metal/renderers"
ActionController.add_renderer :my_custom_renderer do |template, options|
  self.mime_type ||= Mime::HTML
  self.response_body = render_to_string(template).sub(/^/, 
                                                '\1<h1>Rendering Injection</h1>')
end
```

In app/views/custom_renderer_test/index.my_custom_renderer.erb:

```
<h1>A message "Rendering Injection" should appear above</h1>
```

In app/controllers/custom_renderer_test_controller.rb:

```
class CustomRenderingTestController < ApplicationController
  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      # does not go through my custom renderer!
      format.my_custom_renderer 
      # although it works if I explicitly do:
      # format.my_custom_renderer { render :my_custom_renderer => 'index' }
    end
  end
end
```

And, finally, in config/routes.rb:

```
root :to => "custom_rendering_test#index"
```

Starting up a server and going to the root page should display the message from my_custom_renderer, but it does not. I've tried debugging Rails source step by step, but looks like I don't understand rendering architecture well-enough.

Can someone please give me a hint on what the problem is?

Comment: You need to pass the format variable, so you'd need to set up the route to pass it.

Comment: Rails 3 passes it for all the routes automatically. Still, tried adding it -- does not work. (I did:  `match "/test(.:format)" => "custom_rendering_test#index"` and
  `root :to => redirect("/test.my_custom_renderer")`)

Comment: Got it to work (updated the question), but not in a nice way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What might help is to create a responder (and use the newer `respond_with`) with the explicit method:

```
class ActionController::Responder
  def to_my_custom_renderer
    controller.render :my_custom_renderer => controller.action_name
  end
end
```